# Yii retrieve data from database using createcommand and tally it with a variable

Tags: php, yii

Created a query like below.

```
    <?php
      $notf = $not->id;
      $currDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $list=Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select id from tbl where start_dt <= '$currDate' and end_dt >= '$currDate'");
      $res = $list->queryColumn();
      // Code for get the value of the column...
    ?>
```

Now I would like to retrieve a data which I want to tally with `$notf` like

```
<?php if(!$variable === $notf){ ?>
```

I have used `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc('$qry')` and then `$data = $row['field_name']` in php to get the data. **What should I do in Yii ?**

I am new in Yii.

Comment: You might need to use queryScalar() instead of queryColumn()

Comment: Try `queryRow()` with `$row['fieldName']` or `queryScalar()` instead.

Comment: When you sat 'tally' you mean count, right? If so, why not change your query to "SELECT count(*) ..."?